# How to find class definition in html?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web-design. Making my first website, which is really complicated. I'm trying to look at other websites I like and copy little things from them. That's why it's hard, I can't understand the code. Anyways,

If I downloaded a sample website template and open the index.html in notepad++, I see things like:

```
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/johndoe"  target="_blank" class="twitter"></a>
```

how do I find where `class="twitter"` is defined? I'm guess it may be in style.css what if there are more than one css and js?

Comment: Open the page in a browser, right click(mouse) and inspect element.

Comment: search the template using your editor?

Comment: You can find this out using an Element Inspector inside of your web browser.

Comment: Thanks! 'inspect element' is very helpful. Would you know where I can learn all the tabs and how to navigate 'inspect element'? Is there a tutorial somewhere about inspect element?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using Chrome, right-click the element and select "Inspect Element".

The Dev Tools "Styles" panel shows you where CSS declarations come from:

[image]

Other browsers will be similar.

Comment: Thanks! 'inspect element' is very helpful. Would you know where I can learn all the tabs and how to navigate 'inspect element'? Is there a tutorial somewhere about inspect element?

Comment: Try them and see how they work :) Try https://developer.chrome.com/devtools and https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/videos - the top two Google hits for "devtools getting started". Search around for yourself and you'll find more!

Answer (score 4):

A class is not actually 'defined'. It is just a property to categorize the element.

That property can then be used in CSS to apply a specific style to the element. It can also be used in JavaScript to find the element and apply some functionality to it.

But it's perfectly possible that an element has a class property that occurs nowhere in JavaScript or CSS.

In the developer tools, you can see what styles are applied to an element. With each piece of styling you can also see the CSS file where it came from, including the styles that are overridden by other styles.

That doesn't give you all the reference to the class, though! If the CSS has a style that says `div.twitter`, it won't be applied to this element. Just as well, `a.twitter:hover` will only be applied when the element is hovered. So browsing the dev tools will not give you all references to a certain class. The best (only) way would be to just view the source of all CSS files and search in them.

Comment: Chrome's dev tools (maybe others) do allow you to add psuedo-classes on demand - click the dotted rectangle containing an arrow at the top of the style panel.

Comment: @joews Thanks. I know that is possible, but still it won't give you a full proof (or easy) way to find references to a class. As I understood it, that is what was asked. It does however provide a very convenient way to test `:hover` or other special states for those elements, so it's a very useful feature indeed. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

Using Chrome or Safari dev tools, you can select that element, and you'll see in the inspector the files in which each applied rule is defined.

EDIT:

I think Firefox dev tools show this as well.

Answer (score 2):

Open the page in a browser, like Chrome or Firefox, right click and inspect the element, You should see the source, there you can see the class.

but tbh, if you want to learn about webdevelopment. check guides and try out a free course like http://www.codeacedemy.com I think it's far more effective then 
simply copy paste from other sites

http://www.codecademy.com/en/skills/make-a-website

http://www.codecademy.com/en/skills/make-an-interactive-website

http://www.w3schools.com

Answer (score 1):

Curiously, I found a solution:

We now know that you have the whole website downloaded, great, so apart from opening it in Chrome/FF/IE(yes, that works, too, don't overlook the bravest explorer who asks us to set it as default) and check from "Dev Tools", we can open the HTML file in [Sublime Text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3), and hover onto a class; you will see something like this:

[image]

Now you see all the definitions(better to say "occurrences", because it only does a simple search in all `css` and `js` files; but quicker to view than manual search)